# null == 0 returning true in function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following function that makes absolutely no sense why it fails:

```js
function GetPlayersMap ( map, id ){
    let compressedMap = [];
    for(let x = 0; x < map.length; x++){
        for(let y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++){
            if(map[x][y].claimant_id != null) {console.log(map[x][y].claimant_id); console.log(id)}
            if(id == null || map[x][y].claimant_id != id){
                map[x][y].count = null;
            }
            if(map[x][y].claimant_id != null){
                console.log(map[x][y]);
                compressedMap.push(map[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }
    return compressedMap;
}
```

`map` is a 2d array of objects, `map.count` is an int that is never `null` when entering the function.  `id` is an int that can be `null`.  The expected result is that on an `id` input of `0` it return a `compressedMap` with one object that matched that.  The function is called twice, with the same `map` and an `id` of `0` then `null`.  What is printed in console is

```
0
0
Tile { x: 0, y: 0, claimant_id: 0, count: null, fake_claimed: false }
0
null
Tile { x: 0, y: 0, claimant_id: 0, count: null, fake_claimed: false }
```

This is printed regardless of if I change the 5th line to

```
if(id == null){
```

(which makes no sense, this means it is matching 0 to null)or

```
if(map[x][y].claimant_id != id){
```

Only when I change it to

```
if(false){
```

do I get the expected output of

```
0
0
Tile { x: 0, y: 0, claimant_id: 0, count: 1, fake_claimed: false }
0
null
Tile { x: 0, y: 0, claimant_id: 0, count: 1, fake_claimed: false }
```

I added a simplified example of the code

```js
class Tile {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.claimant_id = null;
    this.count = 1;
    this.fake_claimed = false;
  }
}

var map = []
for (let x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
  map.push([]);
  for (let y = 0; y < 1000; y++) {
    map[x].push(new Tile(x, y));
  }
}
map[0][0].claimant_id = 0;

function GetPlayersMap(map, id) {
  let compressedMap = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++) {
      if (map[x][y].claimant_id != null) {
        console.log(map[x][y].claimant_id);
        console.log(id)
      }
      if (id == null || map[x][y].claimant_id != id) {
        map[x][y].count = null;
      }
      if (map[x][y].claimant_id != null) {
        console.log(map[x][y]);
        compressedMap.push(map[x][y]);
      }
    }
  }
  return compressedMap;
}

GetPlayersMap(map, 0);
GetPlayersMap(map, null);
GetPlayersMap(map, 0);
```

Comment: Best to always use `===` and `!==`, abstract equality comparison is too strange and unintuitive

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately no luck

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that accurately reproduces the behaviour? I can't quite see what's wrong just by looking at he code - I'm not sure which console.log is executed when.

Comment: I'm not saying it'll solve the problem, I'm saying that it makes code *much* easier to understand at a glance

Comment: I believe the whole project is the minimal reproducible example, I attempted to simplify it, but that returns the expected result.

Comment: try using node debugger, also knowing node version would be helpful

Comment: @ishidex2 node v10.16.3, and I'll try it thanks

Comment: Running the example in the code snippet, it behaves exactly as I'd expect - the first tile has a count of 1, the second has a count of null. The second is null because we passed in an id of null, obviously.

Comment: @Hecksa yeah, it returns the expected result, that is where my issue comes in, it doesn't when actually used in project

Comment: No, the logging is merely for debugging

Comment: it's confusing me like hell,  what is what so should the second function return something or just not find something? Maybe you want to edit id to searchVal or something

Comment: @fubar I am confused as to what you are asking

Comment: if i get this correctly you are asking why `map[x][y].claimant_id != null`  and `id == null` are interchangable on line five of the first code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> map.count is an int that is never null when entering the function.

I kindly disagree with that statement since because you don't copy the array or the objects nested inside so that `map[x][y].count = null;` will edit the array/object permanent. This might lead to the impresiion that `null==0` though the code was never executed in that call.

Below the code with a deep-copy. Does this answer your question?

Since you have allot of data, I assume give the post about [deep-copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) a read.

```js
class Tile {
    constructor(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.claimant_id = null;
      this.count = 1;
      this.fake_claimed = false;
    }
}
  
  var map = []
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    map.push([]);
    for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
      map[x].push(new Tile(x, y));
    }
  }
  map[0][0].claimant_id = 0;
  
  function GetPlayersMap(map, id) {

    // added copy of array
    const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(map));

    let compressedMap = [];

    for (let x = 0; x < copy.length; x++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < copy[x].length; y++) {

        if (id == null || copy[x][y].claimant_id != id) {
          copy[x][y].count = null;

        }
        if (copy[x][y].claimant_id != null) {
          console.log(copy[x][y]);
          compressedMap.push(copy[x][y]);

        }
      }
    }
    return compressedMap;
  }
  
  GetPlayersMap(map, 0);
  GetPlayersMap(map, null);
  GetPlayersMap(map, 0);
```

Comment: Yep that fixed it, I thought the function call was copying the array, I see my mistake now.